# Consistency errors in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server-2000, corruption

I have SQL Server 2000 and ever since upgrading from SP2 to SP4 random errors began happening.  Mostly overflow errors, sometimes in `SqlDateTime` and sometimes in data type `numeric`.

For example, right now I have a column with `1099511628.776` as its value, the column type is `decimal(18,3)` which can hold up to 10^38, so clearly this is not an overflow, however when I try to update that column and set it to 1 I get the error `Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type
numeric`.

I ran `DBCC CHECKDB` on the database and I got 6 consistency errors in two tables, for the first table:

```
Msg 8970, Level 16, State 1, Line 1  
Row error: Object ID 578101100, index ID 0, page ID (1:24157), row ID 61.
Column 'wh_id' was created NOT NULL, but is NULL in the row.
```

Second table:

```
Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Line 1   
Object ID 933578364, index ID 0: Page (1:7160) could not be processed. 
See other errors for details.

Msg 8939, Level 16, State 12, Line 1  
Table error: Object ID 933578364, index ID 0, page (1:7160). 
Test (*(((int*) &m_reservedB) + i) == 0) failed. Values are 0 and 65536.

Msg 8944, Level 16, State 2, Line 1  
Table error: Object ID 933578364, index ID 0, page (1:7223), row 12. 
Test (!(hdr->r_tagA & (VERSION_MASK | RECTAG_RESV_A | RECTAG_RESV_B))) failed. 
Values are 17 and 193.`

Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Line 1  
Object ID 933578364, index ID 0: Page (1:7254) could not be processed. 
See other errors for details.`

Msg 8939, Level 16, State 106, Line 1  
Table error: Object ID 933578364, index ID 0, page (1:7254). 
Test (m_freeCnt == freeCnt) failed. Values are 2442 and 2444.`
```

Now for the first error, I tried running the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE wh_id IS NULL
```

However, it returns zero rows. For the rest of the errors, I don't know how to query the table to find the the bad row(s).

How can I fix these consistency errors, and are they the reason for the random errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those errors are corrupt pages in the actual table themselves.  You will need to restore the table.  There's no way to repair the issue without loosing data as the corruption is in the base table.

Comment: How would I partially restore the tables? Also is there anyway to identify the corrupted rows so I can enter them again?

Comment: Using the native tools you would need to restore the entire database, then simply query the restored table looking for rows which don't exist in the table that was corrupt.